# Clustering with pm2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I wrote an Express application which I would like to scale using pm2. This express app performs a couple jobs which I only need to execute once. When I am going to start multiple instances of my jobs using pm2 I assume that it will also run the defined jobs multiple times.

So how can I make my application aware that only one instance has to run specific code portions?

**Code example:**

```
agenda.every('1 hours', 'refreshProfiles')
```

Comment: nice question, but do you *have* to use pm2 for this purpose? can you not start the other part of the code when one is done using javascript?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your idea. Do you mean if I can break the jobs out into it's own application?

Comment: can I see some of your code, or just a small sample ? @kentor

Comment: also, I don't think you can do that, pm2 controls the whole app byitself, but not the app's functions.